# How can I run my shiny app without calling library("shiny") beforehand?

Tags: r, shiny

I apologize for this extremely noobish question, but I can't find the answer. I just finished writing my R Shiny app and am preparing to send it off to my network guy so he can load it on my company server.

However, to run my app, I currently have to do the commands:

```
>library("shiny")
>runApp("myApp")
```

I don't want the network guy to have to deal with running library("shiny"), so how can I put this in my code? I already have

```
library(shiny)
```

in my server.R

In addition, I have many packages implemented, including googleVis, ggplot2, and reshape2. I have these as

```
library(reshape2)
library(googleVis)
library(ggplot2)
```

But when using my app on a new computer I have to use 'install.packages()'. Will my network guy or app users have to worry about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you have `shiny` package installed on the company's server, you can just call

```
shiny::runApp()
```

What `::` does is bringing a symbol from a package that hasn't being imported yet.

I have the following shell script `runapp` which lets me run shiny apps from the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
R -e "shiny::runApp('$1')"
```

So I can say `runapp directory-with-shiny-script/` and it runs the app.

Comment: You do not need to launch bash just to start to launch R; you could just use `Rscript` or `littler` which is my preference: `r -lshiny -e'runApp(".")'` is my preferred idiom.

Comment: Well, the overhead is very little, and I get a convenience of less typing. But thanks for the tip

Comment: There can not be less typing than launching `r` :-)  And yes, it can be used for `shebang` mode too.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's like asking how to run `R` without `R`.

And yes, to run the code on a new computer, you will have to provide its dependencies.

Comment: Look at this app for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=radyant&oq=radyant&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i60l3j69i59.2038j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. He has a lot of imported libraries (code:https://github.com/mostly-harmless/radyant/blob/master/inst/marketing/global.R). How can a user of this app like me see everything without having all libraries imported, etc. Is this just abstracted from me and taken care of by the server? I'm confused about this because I'm wondering whether I have to give my network guy any specific details.